# How to increase row size in SQL Server CE

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

While inserting rows into SQL Server CE in WP7 I'm getting a `SQLCeException` that says

> The table definition or the row size exceeds the maximum row size of
>   8060 bytes.

What is the way to increase the row size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has a **hard and fixed** system limit at 8K for a page size.

There is **NO WAY** to increase that.

The solution will be to re-architect your design to work around this.